# What is the disadvantage of using the $scope as variable in angularjs, to share $scope of a controller inside the app.run?

Tags: angularjs

What is the disadvantage of using the `$scope` as variable in AngularJS, to share `$scope` of a controller inside the `app.run()`?
Actually I am doing that to make code generic to be called from all the controllers with same function in `app.run()`.

The function I am using is with the

```
$rootScope.getUserInfo = function($scope){
  $scope.userinfo = '---------';
}
```

where `$scope` is the variable that I am passing from every controller like that

```
$rootScope.getUserInfo($scope);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's inherently something wrong with passing around a scope. People do this a lot in AngularJS services and it's internally done a lot, too: your created controller is passed a scope to work with.

However, I would say it's not *necessary* in your example to  have `getUserInfo` to depend on a scope being passed. Why not return the user information and have the caller put it on the scope? That way, you can use it in parts of your app that don't have a scope.

Comment: thank you for reply
user info was just an example, actually I have 300 lines functions, and they don't return anything.the values of angularjs variables that I used in controller are being set automatically if I pass the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $scope, you can use var vm = this; and define everything in that controller with vm.variablename_or_funcname instead of $scope.variablename_or_funcname

And you can attach that controller in html like ng-controller = "mycontroller as vm"

More info:
https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/